# jQuery Custom Element Rotate Help

Tags: jquery, rotation, banner

Hey!
I am trying to code a simple content/image rotating banner that I can click left or right arrows to rotate the content..

I have everything coded and it works but in a very beginners way and would really appreciate a better, more robust way to do it.

```
jQuery("span.left-arrow").click(function() {
    var visible = jQuery("#home_slider .slide:visible").attr("id");
    var slide1 = jQuery("#home_slider #slide1");
    var slide2 = jQuery("#home_slider #slide2");
    var slide3 = jQuery("#home_slider #slide3");
    if (jQuery(visible == "slide1")) {
        jQuery("#home_slider #slide1:visible").fadeOut(function() {
            slide3.fadeIn();
        });
    }
    if (jQuery(visible == "slide2")) {
        jQuery("#home_slider #slide2:visible").fadeOut(function() {
            slide1.fadeIn();
        });
    }
    if (jQuery(visible == "slide3")) {
        jQuery("#home_slider #slide3:visible").fadeOut(function() {
            slide2.fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
// right arrow
jQuery("span.right-arrow").click(function() {
    var visible = jQuery("#home_slider .slide:visible").attr("id");
    var slide1 = jQuery("#home_slider #slide1");
    var slide2 = jQuery("#home_slider #slide2");
    var slide3 = jQuery("#home_slider #slide3");
    if (jQuery(visible == "slide1")) {
        jQuery("#home_slider #slide1:visible").fadeOut(function() {
            slide2.fadeIn();
        });
    }
    if (jQuery(visible == "slide2")) {
        jQuery("#home_slider #slide2:visible").fadeOut(function() {
            slide3.fadeIn();
        });
    }
    if (jQuery(visible == "slide3")) {
        jQuery("#home_slider #slide3:visible").fadeOut(function() {
            slide1.fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it works already, what kind of improvements are you looking at exactly? Otherwise if you're looking for a plugin, you might want to look at http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html.

Comment: Working is one thing but the code is way too bloated and not very robust...I would rather do this in an array with each function to dynamically pick up the number of elements to rotate...etc...but need some guidance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

**EDIT:** the click handlers will now allow you to "loop" forward and backwards.

```
// a reference to the currently shown slide
// you will have to initialize this somewhere
var currentSlide;

jQuery("span.left-arrow").click(function() {
    currentSlide.fadeOut(function(){
        // if it has a previous sibling, use the previous sibling
        // otherwise set it to the last slide
        currentSlide = currentSlide.prev().length ? currentSlide.prev() : currentSlide.siblings().last();
        currentSlide.fadeIn();
    });
}

jQuery("span.right-arrow").click(function() {
    currentSlide.fadeOut(function(){
        currentSlide = currentSlide.next().length ? currentSlide.next() : currentSlide.siblings().first();
        currentSlide.fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Using this method you don't have to give each slide a unique ID, but the slide elements must be the only children of `#home_slider`.

You could initialize with something like:

```
jQuery(function(){
    // this loops through all slides when the page loads and
    // assigns the first slide to the variable currentSlide
    // and hides all the others
    jQuery("#home_slider").children().each(function(index){
        index == 0 ? currentSlide = jQuery(this) : jQuery(this).hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: @ZDYN - thanks for the code however what I am trying to understand is why this needs to be initialized?  I thought this fires only when clicked? Sorry if that is a newbie question...

Comment: @Rick, I'm using the variable `currentSlide` to keep track of which slide is "visible". That way, in your click event, instead of checking each slide to see which one is visible, you already have a reference to it (i.e. `currentSlide`). But when the page first loads, you need to assign to the variable which slide is active, otherwise it will be null.

Comment: @ZDYN - there is only 1 issue with this...what i did with your code is added the specific selector in next(".slide") so it knows to only go to the siblings with that selector.  But now when I click next and if there is no other ".slide", it just stops and doesn't loop around to the first slide.  How can I make it loop back to the first slide?

Comment: @Rick, see my edit. It will now allow you to loop around to the first slide going forwards, and loop around to the last going backwards. If you don't want to loop around going backwards, revert it to the original code as necessary.

Comment: @ZDYN - perfect that works however I still had to add in next(".slide") and prev(".slide") and siblings(".slide") for it to work or else when I click next/prev, different elements in the chain will start to fadeout...So am I correct to add those? Thanks again.

Comment: @Rick, it depends on what your HTML looks like, but if that works for you, then go with it.